# Live Sass Compiller, расширение в VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

вопрос такой. Решил перейти с Sublime на VS Code, нашёл полезное расширение, которое компилирует код sass в css, но файл .css сохраняется в той же папке, где и сам .sass файл. Не могу найти настройки, чтобы изменить папку сохранения скомпилированного файла.

Comment: Вроде их надо менять с помощью .md файла, но я ни разу не работал с файлами такого расширения и не знаю как их правильно использовать

Comment: какое расширение-то?

Comment: Плюсую предыдущему клиенту. Если нужна помощь в расширении, то потрудитесь указать его точное название.

Comment: В названии вопроса же написал: Live Sass Compiller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Устанавливаем в `VS Code` расширение `Live Sass Compiller`
2. Открываем *параметры* в `VS Code` *по умолчанию, на Русском языке, сочетание клавиш:* ***ctrl+б***
3. Вводим в строку **параметры поиска** текст: ***`liveSassCompile.settings.formats`
   VS Code*** находит этот параметр и отображает возможные действия с ним ниже строки поиска.
4. Находим ниже ссылку: Изменить в `settings.json` и нажимаем на неё.
5. В открывшемся окне видим слева интересуемый нас параметр и его настройки по умолчанию:

   ```
     "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [{
     "format": "expanded",
     "extensionName": ".css",
     "savePath": null
   }],
   ```

В окне справа ваш файл настроек `settings.json` в который вы и добавьте этот параметр (можно просто скопировать то, что я указал выше.

6. Далее вам необходимо настроить путь к файлу ***`SASS` откуда будет браться ваш код*** и пусть к файлу ***`CSS` куда будет компилироваться код из вашего файла SASS***.
7. К примеру, если у вас в директории `APP` расположена директория: `SASS` в котором находится редактируемый вами файл `*.sass` и в этой же папке `APP` также расположена директория `CSS` в которой вы хотите, чтобы компилировался уже готовый файл `*.css`, то настройка будет выглядеть примерно так:

   ```
   "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [{
   "format": "expanded",
   "extensionName": ".css", *//Имя файла, который будет формироваться (здесь не указано имя, а указано, только расширение. Поэтому имя файла будет такое же, как и имя файла источника sass.*
   "savePath": "/css/"  *//Путь к дериктории, где будет формироваться скомпелированный файл .css*
   }],
   ```

Вообще настраивать пути можно более широко.

[Вот тут](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md)  более подробно всё указано, но на английском языке.

Comment: у меня почему то не работает данный способ

Answer (score 2):

Сегодня, 28.06.2020 появилась странная проблема с VSCode
Перестали компилироваться scss-файлы

**Сразу пишу решение**:
`savePath": "~/../css/"`

Я использую плагин Live Saas Compiler.
В настройках settings.json у плагина есть настройка

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
  {
    "format": "expanded",
    "autoprefix": "last 5 versions",
    "extensionName": ".css",
    "savePath": "css",
  }
],
```

Сегодня с утра строчка
`"autoprefix": "last 5 versions",`
стала выдавать ошибку
*Property autoprefix is not allowed.*

а строчка
`"savePath": "css",`
ошибку
*String does not match the pattern of "^[~|/|\]".*

Пробовал для исправления

1. Закомментировать строчку "autoprefix" и добавить в строчку  "savePath" знак "/" вначале, в конце, с двух сторон... (ошибки пропадают, компилирование не запускается)
2. Переустановить плагины
3. Переустановить vscode

Ничего из перечисленного не помогло.
Из [мануала](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md) подошло решение
`savePath": "~/../css/"`

А все другие способы, указанные там -- не работают.

ошибка появилась на:
Windows 7, VSCode 1.46.1, Live Sass Compiler v3.0.0
Кириллических букв в пути к файлам нет.

Итоговая рабочая настройка:
`

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": false,
   "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": "~/../css/"
        }
    ],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 10 versions"
    ],
"liveSassCompile.settings.showOutputWindow": true,
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "",
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Допустим используется БЭМ, блоки лежат в отдельной папке, в style.scss собираются

```
@import "global";
@import "blocks/header"; и т.д.
```

После компиляции кода в css в папке создаются файлы с расширением *.css, а не обновляется сам файл со стилями style.css.

Вот настройка:

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        {
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "/css"
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не создавались файлы *.css нужно в названия доп. файлов *.scss добавлять нижнее подчеркивание, например /scss/_file1.scss и подключать эти файлы в основной файл /scss/style.scss. Тогда будет создаваться один файл style.css

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не создавались файлы *.css нужно в названия доп. файлов *.scss добавлять нижнее подчеркивание, например /scss/_file1.scss и подключать эти файлы в основной файл /scss/style.scss. Тогда будет создаваться один файл style.css

Выполнив все условия, все равно сохраняються даже с нижним подчеркиванием. как исправить?

нашел решение, создал папку в нутри /scss/папка и переместил в нее _file1.scss _file2.scss переподключил их пути в основном файле /scss/style.scss. и все заработало, больше не компилит файлы с нижним подчеркиванием.